# Is it possible to use the '&' symbol instead of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

I know that a pointer points to a memory address, but is it possible to just use the `&` symbol instead of a pointer?

Comment: `&` is a way to *get* a pointer to a location.

Comment: It gets the address of the variable, yes. That... is a pointer... to the location where the variable is. "Address of the variable" and "pointer to the variable" mean the same thing: a number that indicates the variable's position in the address space. As for the last question, I don't understand the distinction you are trying to draw.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you'd use "& instead of pointers"?

Comment: @P.P - In this case  I think your question, although fair, is kind of redundant with what is being asked, don't you think?.  i.e. the essence of the question is _how do I use `&` and`*`?_  And you are asking  _How would_ ***you*** _use `&` and `*`?_

Comment: @ryyker OP demonstrated that he generally understood pointers and instead asked a (language design sort of) question or that's what I thought. So I asked OP to provide a hypothetical example that uses "& instead of pointers". I don't think OP asked "how do I use & and \*" and I don't really understand how your answer answers that (although OP accepted it *shrugs*). I don't think I was the only one who didn't (and still don't) understand the question...

Comment: @P.P - Okay, fair enough, I see your rational.  As for my answer, it was based somewhat on assumptions of what was missing in OP understanding, so I simply tried to fill in the gap (against what was already covered, with no overlaps.) with an illustration showing a very commonly mis-understood and mis-used idea with those new to C, thus the reason to start my post with _"Another"_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&v` will get you the address of the variable `v`, but `&v` is an r-value, not an l-value.

In order to have an l-value containing the address of a variable you would have to use the `*` syntax, as in `T *p = &v;`.

Answer (score 2):

Another common use case for the `&` operator, which is aptly named the [address of](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/25580/address-of-operator--c) operator,  is in function parameters, for functions that are used to update the value stored at an address.  In the example below, because only the address of the value at location `var1` is passed, it allows the *value* at that address to be changed. Upon the function return, the value is changed.

```
void squareInt(int *var);//prototype
void squareInt_2(int var);//legal, but wrong

int main(void)
{
    int var1 = 10;
    squareInt(&var1);
    printf("var1: %d\n", var1);//updates value
    squareInt_2(var1);
    printf("var1: %d", var1);//will not update value

    return 0;
}

void squareInt(int *var)
{
    *var *= *var;
}

void squareInt_2(int var)
{
    var *= var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no, ***`&`*** gets you the address of a variable, but you cannot read the value of such variable or set it using that operator.

for doing that you need to use ***`*`***

Comment: the 'address operator' and 'dereference operator' ARE pointer operations.  Maybe you mean 'without explicit pointer lvalues'.  If so, then the answer is somewhere between no, through 'unlikely', 'probably' all the way to yes.